# jQuery UI, Asp.NET, IE, Disappearing Buttons

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an Asp.NET website being written in C#. There is a DataGrid () that has three columns of buttons (). I an using jQuery UI to redesign site and I wanted to style the buttons in this grid. After finding no way to do it with HTML/ASP markup, I decided to use a jQuery selector to set the style. This works to style the buttons, but in IE 8, when I hover over a button, the rest of the buttons disappear and they don't come back until I refresh the page. My javascript looks like this:

```
$('input[type~="submit"]').button ();
$('input[type~="submit"]').css ('font-size', '10px');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just tried $(':submit').button () and I got the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was my lack of a DOCTYPE declaration. Making it strict fixed the issue.